# Haskell error: "The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression"

Tags: haskell, tuples

I am currently writing a Haskell program for one of my classes. The code is contained below.

When I try to compile, it gives me the error that  "The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression". However, as far as I can tell writeFile should qualify for this? I presume there's some other error in my code I haven't noticed that's causing this.

```
type Network = [(Int, Int)]

fileParse :: FilePath -> IO Network
fileParse filename = do
    contents  <- readFile filename 
    let networks = read contents :: Network
    return networks

greaterSwap :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
greaterSwap (a, b) 
      | b > a = (b, a)
      | otherwise = (a, b) 

printNetwork :: Network -> String
printNetwork [] = ""
printNetwork (x:[]) = show(fst(x)) ++ " -- " ++ show(snd(x))
printNetwork (x:xs) = show(fst(x)) ++ " -- " ++ show(snd(x)) ++ "\n" ++ printNetwork xs



main :: IO ()
   main = do
   args <- getArgs
      case args of
         "Read":filename:_ ->
            do contents <- fileParse filename 
               networks <- map greaterSwap contents
               endString <- printNetwork networks 
               writeFile "network.txt" endString
```

So far I've tried fiddling with the makeup of several of the functions but haven't yet landed on what the problem might be. I'm aware there are other posts on here regarding a similar error, but I haven't found any that are directly applicable. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems incorrectly indented. `main = do` line should be 2 spaces to the left, and so should the `case args of` line.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin oh my goodness thank you so much! i didn't even register that the indentation was incorrect